# Close menu on mobile devices with anchor link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile-devices

I have been reading in this community and testing codes but I can not close the menu.
I have created a simple JSFiddle to understand it. I would like to close it using jQuery. The problem is only in mobile view. In this example, the user clicks on the "MORE" menu and a "NEWS" item appears. "NEWS" is an anchor link and when the user clicks there, the menu is still open. This is the problem. How can I close the menu?

I have tried everything.

```
jQuery(".item-131").css( 'pointer-events', 'none' );
jQuery(".item-131").attr('onmouseover','');
jQuery(".item-131").off('mouseenter mouseleave');
jQuery(".item-131").unbind("mouseenter mouseleave");
```

But I can not close the menu.

See my JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/karmany/gc0ku8on/

Answer (score 0):

If you could show your cursor on mobile you'd see that when you click menu the cursor is still above the menu button until you actually tap off it — now you could have an on click event that closes the menu when it's clicked?

Comment: I tried
```jQuery(".item-216").click(function() {
     //jQuery(".item-131").css( 'pointer-events', 'none' );
     jQuery(".item-216").attr('onmouseover','');
     //jQuery(".item-131").off('mouseenter mouseleave');
     //jQuery("li.item-131").unbind("mouseenter mouseleave");
     //jQuery("li.item-216").unbind("mouseenter mouseleave");
    });```
But nothing works.

Comment: Looking into it I think I would do any hover states using a class called `.hover` so that you can toggle the class using jQuery instead of relying on. That way you can do: ```$('.item-216).on('mousedown', function() { $(this).toggle('hover'); })